# Attribute on backing property in class primary constructor

Tags: c#, c#-12.0

How can I add a attribute on a compiler generated backing property for a paramater in a C# 12 class primary constructor ?

I tried:

```
class C([field: JsonIgnore] int X) { 
  int F() => X +1; 
}
```

But I get a warning

> warning CS0657: 'field' is not a valid attribute location for this declaration. Valid attribute locations for this declaration are 'param'. All attributes in this block will be ignored.

And the attribute is ignored, same for `[property: JsonIgnore]`.

(using [param: .. ] puts the attribute on the ctor param which is not what I'm after)

(also note I am trying to avoid explicitly defining the field in the class)

Note that I can achieve pretty much the exact thing with records [see](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAUEEsC2UECeAwgPYB2yMCcAxjCQsgD4ACATAIwCwAULwNoBBGFSzA4MCAFVkUAOYQAFMNHjJAFXwKYyAHSCANgYA0AAkMGSAdwCycAzCwAHAxFMBeU2CgHkEMwCSZAAWENiSACYeXj5+AJQAurwsAMymfj4QUezmIgimILmqEm4A3qYAvry8SDQMUQBKivxgWBAGEYUqCAmmWGQwpgAacablvKZ9A6YAYoqj7gB8w6YA1BwA3Ka8FUA)

Comment: what are you trying to do???? i have no idea based on your explanation.

Comment: I am trying to put an attribute on a class field when the class is defined using the shorthand C# 13 primary constructor (that is the field is not explicitly declared)

Comment: a constructor has nothing to do with a field or its declaration.

Comment: you are not using it correctly from what i can see... you still have to declare class properties

Comment: a FIELD is an class instance variable.,. not a constructor param

Comment: From that page: "2. Primary constructor parameters aren't members of the class. For example, a primary constructor parameter named `param` can't be accessed as `this.param`."

Comment: @TMcKeown just read the doc or try it in VC22 ... `class C2(int X) { int F() => X +1; }` is a valid class declaration. The compiler creates a backing field for `X`, I want to add an attribute to it see https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAUEEsC2UECeAwgPYB2yMCcAxjCQsgD4ACATAAREAUWZMHABoBKDgG8OAWABQHDnwEAxbqIC8APiEcA1AEYA3FOkBfIA

Comment: you are not understanding... that is shorthand for constructors not instance members

Comment: But the compiler creates a backing field for the constructor parameter. See sharplab. I want an attribute on that field

Comment: If this was a record, adding `[field: JsonIgnore]` in the primary constructor would achieve  exactly what I want. I don't understand why it is not valid on a class primary ctor

Comment: from the doc:  Primary constructor parameters aren't members of the class. For example, a primary constructor parameter named param can't be accessed as this.param.

Comment: I know that. Please read my comments again

Comment: see the sharplab link, the compiler auto generates `CompilerGenerated] private int <X>PC__BackingField;` .. I want an attribute on _that_

Comment: they are not members... it is all resolved to normal C# once the compiler does its job.

Comment: you can't... says you can't

Comment: But I can on records which is essentially the same idea of primary ctors .. see https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQAUEEsC2UECeAwgPYB2yMCcAxjCQsgD4ACATAIwCwAULwNoBBGFSzA4MCAFVkUAOYQAFMNHjJAFXwKYyAHSCANgYA0AAkMGSAdwCycAzCwAHAxFMBeU2CgHkEMwCSZAAWENiSACYeXj5+AJQAurwsAMymfj4QUezmIgimILmqEm4A3qYAvry8SDQMUQBKivxgWBAGEYUqCAmmWGQwpgAacablvKZ9A6YAYoqj7gB8w6YA1BwA3Ka8FUA

Comment: the spec says you can use the params in functions and properties, it says you can use them in the body of the declaring type. But it does not say that they are properties.

Comment: When I reflect on the class the property is there as is seen sharplab but I guess maybe the spec doesn't mandate them ? so there is no way to have an attribute there ?

Comment: @kofifus what's behind all these questions? What do you care what the backing field for an auto-property is called? Fields are internal implementation details which is why they aren't serialized by default. Only properties are part of a type's API. The primary constructor doesn't change that. You can use `nameof(Foo.Phones)` to get the name of a property (or even a field). You can use `GetProperties` to get all properties, although reflection has it own costs. `System.Text.Json` can use source generators to avoid the runtime cost of reflection.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my code (https://github.com/kofifus/F/wiki/F) has a debug time validator that reflects on all classes/members/methods in the solution and makes assertions on them, I am reflecting on different forms of classes with primary constructors  hence my interest

Comment: In that case treat primary constructors as plain old constructors. They definitely *don't* create properties. Fields with developer-provided names are only created if used by the rest of the code. That's little different from what you'd do in an older constructor. The behavior in the [Initialize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/primary-constructors#initialize-property) section doesn't reflect the actual behavior in 8 RC1. And since it's RC1, this isn't going to change

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what is the difference in 8 RC1 ? where can I see it please

Comment: 8 RC1 is a go-live release (you can use it in production) which means the language isn't going to change any more. Only bugs will be fixed. The *features* are frozen. If the primary constructor generates fields now, it will do so for the next decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the primary difference here is that in records the parameters of the primary constructor are directly used to determine the properties and fields of the type, while in structs and classes the primary constructor's fields aren't necessarily creating even a backing field.

For instance:

```
class Test(int x)
{
    private readonly int _x = x;
    public int X => _x;
}
```

In this case there is *no backing field for `x` in the class.* The generated code looks like this instead:

```
class Test
{
    private readonly int _x;

    public int X 
    {
        get
        {
            return _x;
        }
    }

    public Test(int x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }
}
```

Note that the generated constructor doesn't create a backing field at all, it only uses the parameter in the assignment. Which is fine, because the class doesn't need to save that value for later.

You get a backing field (named `<x>PC__BackingField`) when the parameter is used in code somewhere in the class/struct: a property accessor, instance method or similar:

```
class Test(int x)
{
    public int X => _x;
}
```

Becomes:

```
class Test(int x)
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private int <x>PC__BackingField;

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return <x>PC__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public Test(int x)
    {
        <x>PC__BackingField = x;
    }
}
```

So let's imagine that I write the class this way:

```
class Test([field: Attr]int x)
{
    private readonly int _x = x;

    public int X => _x;
}
```

What happens to the `Attr` there when there's no backing field? Yes it's a contrived example, but it's the simplest form to display the issue.

There are two options that I can think of:

1. Adding a `[field: ...]` attribute tag to the parameter forces the creation of a backing field.
2. The attribute only applies in the case where there a backing field would normally be created.

Either option is fine by me, but the language team are really finicky about these things. Outside of `record`s - which use the parameters of their primary constructor explicitly to define the type's properties - primary constructor parameters are exactly that: parameters. The fact that a backing field *may be* created to allow you access to that parameter's value in other code doesn't mean that the backing field *is* the parameter.

Which is mildly annoying, considering the way `record` works.

And don't even get me started on the fact that *Primary Constructor parameters are mutable!!!*

(Come on guys, just a simple little `readonly` in there would make things so much more sane!)

Comment: yes, but int the case of no backing I can add the attribute directly to the explicit field: `class Test(int x) { [Attr] readonly int _x = x;  public int X => _x; }` so that case is not an issue. I think the first case _can_ be fixed as you suggest so the [field:...] will be applicable

Comment: As for your "don't even get my started" comment .. the whole thing is really disappointing. records were the moment when c# should have gotten immutable types but instead they are just some weak syntactic sugar

Comment: @kofifus That's how C# works though: *damn near everything* is syntactic sugar at the end of the day. LINQ query comprehension, async. Hell, even `foreach` is syntactic sugar.